# How to implement more than one event for Android/Java

Tags: java, android, event-handling

I have an class lets say `Downloader` in which i want to have multiple events let's say `OnCompleted` , `ReportProgress` and `OnCancle`.

I want to know how I can add these event to my class. 
I am new to Android/Java. Please give me the sample code if possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the correct interfaces in your class for each kind of event. Then make sure that you implement the methods present in those interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be making a network call, have you looked into AsycTasks? AyncTasks have methods like:

```
onPreExecute()
doInBackGround()
onProgressUpdate()
onPostExecute()
```

If you are using a network you will need to use an AsyncTask.